# My Blender quits after I switch to "cycles render"

Tags: rendering

I am new to Blender, and when I change the render options from  "blender render" to "cycles render", my blender quits itself, and I have to reopen it.

My blender is the latest version (2.75a), and my computer is a 64bits Windows 7.

Could anyone please advise me on this issue?

Best,
Matthew

Comment: Try this: go to C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\config   Delete startup.blend and userpref.blend and reinstall.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Better open a ticket in the blender bug tracker.

Comment: To Cegaton: Thanks but I do not have the startip.blend and userpref.blend in my config folder... I only have a bookmark.txt inside... To Monster: May I know what is a ticker in bug tracker?

Comment: Troubleshooting like this is better suited to BlenderArtists or another forum. Bugs and troubleshooting are outside the realm of what BSE is seeking to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should report it, just in case there's a bug. Versions with number + letter (like 2.35a) have critical fixes, but almost certainly still have bugs that should be reported and documented.

Comment: That is incorrect, blender versions with letters after the release number mean they *contain* critical bug fixes that were found in the original numbered release, so 2.75a is more stable than 2.75.